# How to switch between sqlserver and postgresql using entity framework by parameters

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a small project, and requirements must be allow user switch database between sqlserver and postgresql or more.

I think, i need a parameter to switch database in json configuration file as:

"DatabaseType": "MsSQL"

My question is how to i implement that with entity framework core?

What can i do with DbContext and switch them?

Sorry if my English not good.

Answer (score 1):

For swithing the database with the same DbContext, you need to make sure your database map the DbContext Structor.

For achieve this, you could try define the parameter like

```
{
    "DatabaseType": "MsSQL1",

    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-TestIdentity2_2-C9C6DF1A-1A9A-497A-871E-618806FC959F;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
        "MySqlConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-MySql-2C4FD13B-62DA-4B5D-8C8C-8F9C42CD3A67;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

    },
}
```

Configure in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    var dbType = Configuration["DatabaseType"];
    if (dbType == "MsSQL")
    {
       //change this to your postgresql config
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection"));
    }
    else
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }
});
```

Comment: how about entity framework working with UseMySql or UsemSqlServer